# Mask hostname in URL using httpd and replace it with Load balancer URL

Tags: sas, httpd.conf

We configured a load balanced URL that will direct the request from "sasstudiodev.org.com" to "http://abcd.org.com:7980/SASStudio" . Note that abcd and sasstudiodev do not have same ip address and sasstudiodev is a load balanced URL. Now we would like to ensure that the host name (i.e. abcd) is not visible to end users. Hence when a user types "sasstudiodev.org.com", SAS should connect to the available mid-tier node based on LB algorithm but the URL displayed in the address bar should NEVER expose the host name, ie. it should still show sasstudiodev.org.com/~/~

Is this possible using httpd or URL rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, you already have a load balancer/reverse proxy set up using Apache by default. To see it working, replace port 7980 to 8080. It is a default set up even when you have a single application server.

You need to change the settings for your virtual host and setup redirect, and should be ready to go.